# Select row by value in set after collect_set with pyspark

Tags: select, pyspark, row

Using

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
```

and methods *f.agg* and *f.collect_set* I have created a column colSet within a *dataFrame* as follows:

```
+-------+--------+
| index | colSet |
+-------+--------+
|      1|[11, 13]|
|      2|  [3, 6]|
|      3|  [3, 7]|
|      4|  [2, 7]|
|      5|  [2, 6]|
+-------+--------+
```

Now, how is it possible, using python/ and pyspark, to select only those rows where, for instance, 3 is an element of the array in the colSet entry (where in general there can be far more than only two entries!)?

I have tried using a udf function like this:

```
isInSet = f.udf( lambda vcol, val: val in vcol, BooleanType())
```

being called via

```
dataFrame.where(isInSet(f.col('colSet'), 3))
```

I also tried removing f.col from the caller and using it in the definition of isInSet instead, but neither worked, I am getting an exception:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '3' given input columns: [index, colSet]
```

Any help is appreciated on how to select rows with a certain entry (or even better subset!!!) given a row with a collect_set result.

Comment: use `where(f.array_contains('colSet', 3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original UDF is fine, but to use it you need to pass the value 3 as a literal:

```
dataFrame.where(isInSet(f.col('colSet'), f.lit(3)))
```

But as jxc points out in a comment, using `array_contains` is probably a better choice:

```
dataFrame.where(f.array_contains(f.col('colSet'), 3))
```

I have not done any benchmarking, but in general using UDFs in PySpark is slower than using built-in functions because of the back-and-forth communication between the JVM and the Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I was sincerely thinking about using explode, but for more than 2 or 3 entries, this is just not an option!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution today (after failing Friday evening) without using an udf-method:

```
[3 in x[0] for x in list(dataFrame.select(['colSet']).collect())]
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: This is not a scalable solution, since `collect()` pulls the entire column into local memory on the driver node.

Comment: Yep, it uses an awful lot of memory. I accepted abeboparebop's answer meanwhile!